# Is "fell 50 feet down the ship" grammatical?

Tags: phrase-request

I am wondering how to put "the height from which someone fell" and "from what location someone fell in the same phrase, and trying to do that I struggled to find the correct phrases to put them into words.

One of my failed attempt is the following:

> He fell 50 feet down the ship and ended up in the ice cold water where
>   the Titanic sank some 100 years ago.

What are some common phrases that can be used to express them in the same phrase?

Comment: It's grammatical, but it's somewhat confusing. Do you mean something like, *he fell overboard, dropped 50 feet, and ended up . . .*?

Comment: Perhaps: "He fell off the ship from a height of 50 feet into icy water where..."

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It's hard to construct a phrase that contains these 2 ideas.